# creating a body every 20-30 seconds after it's destroyed

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, box2d, box2d-iphone

Sorry if this sounds too basic, I am not really getting it. In my Cocos2d Box2d game I would like to create a body every 20-30 seconds after it's destroyed (starting with waiting 20-30 seconds before it's created the first time). Below is my method that calls the creation and the destruction. Thanks.

Creating ball:

```
-(void)ballScheduler  {

[self createBall:ballWorld inLayer:ballLayer];
}
```

Destroying ball:

```
-(void)destroyBall{
ballWorld->DestroyBody(ballBody);
ballBody = NULL;
[ballLayer removeChild:ballSprite];
}
```

Comment: You should have a central place to manage your balls.

Comment: yes, I get that. Both of the above methods will be called in that central place or method. But my main issue is setting the time intervals, I believe some BOOL can be used to check for destruction, but I am not sure how to put it all together.

Answer (score 0):

Use actions to measure time interval. So the code within the destroyBall function would be something like that:

```
[self runAction:[CCSequence actions:[CCDelayTime actionWithDuration:20.0],
                                    [CCCallFuncN actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(createNewBody:)],
                                    nil
                ]
];
```

I have used cocos2d a while back, so the code might be not 100% correct, but somewhere within the reach of the correct one. If I can remember correct you can only call runAction on a CCNode or derived class object, so "self" here would need to be the object of the relevant type or maybe the CCScene itself. It all depends how you designed your game, I can't really comment on the implementation without having a look at the code.